# How to solve "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"?

Tags: linux, kernel, dpkg

I am working on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Ubuntu. When I try to execute the following command:

```
sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

I receive the following error:

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
raspberrypi-kernel-headers ist schon die neueste Version (1.20190819~stretch-1).
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 389 nicht aktualisiert.
1 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Es müssen noch 0 B von 3.394 kB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 0 B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes git (--configure):
 Paket ist in einem sehr schlechten inkonsistenten Zustand - Sie sollten es
 nochmal installieren, bevor Sie die Konfiguration versuchen.
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 git
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone provide some help how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: follow the instructions ... *Paket ist in einem sehr schlechten inkonsistenten Zustand - Sie sollten es nochmal installieren, bevor Sie die Konfiguration versuchen*

Comment: I did this, but this does not work.